# How do I iterate over this JSON object?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, json

This is an object that is returned as a `response` in an HTTP POST request:

```
res.body
=> "{\"id\":\"a3adasfaf3\",\"url\":\"https://someurl/a3adasfaf3\",\"created\":\"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z\",\"modified\":\"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z\",\"files_hash\":\"cljhlk2j3l2kj34hlke18\",\"language\":\"ruby\",\"title\":\"Some weird hello world message\",\"public\":false,\"owner\":\"kljhlk2jh34lk2jh4l2kj3h4l2kj4h23l4kjh2l4k\",\"files\":[{\"name\":\"Some-weird-hello-world-message.rb\",\"content\":\"puts \\\"Some weird hello world message.\\\"\\r\\n\"}]}"
```

I am trying to pull out, and translate the various attributes of that `response`. For instance, at the very least the `id` and `url`.

How do I do this?

For the record, I am using Ruby's [NET/HTTP std lib](http://ruby-doc.org/stdlib-2.3.1/libdoc/net/http/rdoc/Net/HTTP.html) to send the POST request and get back this response.

**Edit 1**

For bonus points, all I want is the actual value stored in each attribute (i.e. the actual `id` (which is just a string) and a `url` (which is a typical URL). So if you included how I might both access that attribute and then sanitize it at the same time that would be awesome.

Comment: try  `JSON.parse(res)`

Comment: Hey you can used  `Json.parse(res)["id"]` for id  and for url `Json.parse(res)["url"]`

Comment: @VishalJAIN I am now realizing that I can do that. Thanks.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Use *JSON.parse* to parse the response.

```
response = "{\"id\":\"a3adasfaf3\",\"url\":\"https://someurl/a3adasfaf3\",\"created\":\"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z\",\"modified\":\"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z\",\"files_hash\":\"cljhlk2j3l2kj34hlke18\",\"language\":\"ruby\",\"title\":\"Some weird hello world message\",\"public\":false,\"owner\":\"kljhlk2jh34lk2jh4l2kj3h4l2kj4h23l4kjh2l4k\",\"files\":[{\"name\":\"Some-weird-hello-world-message.rb\",\"content\":\"puts \\\"Some weird hello world message.\\\"\\r\\n\"}]}"

require 'json'

JSON.parse response
# output:
# {"id"=>"a3adasfaf3", "url"=>"https://someurl/a3adasfaf3", "created"=>"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z", "modified"=>"2016-05-30T07:00:58Z", "files_hash"=>"cljhlk2j3l2kj34hlke18", "language"=>"ruby", "title"=>"Some weird hello world message", "public"=>false, "owner"=>"kljhlk2jh34lk2jh4l2kj3h4l2kj4h23l4kjh2l4k", "files"=>[{"name"=>"Some-weird-hello-world-message.rb", "content"=>"puts \"Some weird hello world message.\"\r\n"}]}

response["name"] # => a3adasfaf3
```

Comment: I like where you are going, can you just add a code example and I will accept it.

Comment: This is perfect. Thanks!

Comment: What's the benefit to using `JSON.parse` over `eval(response)`?

Comment: **eval** can be basically used to convert string to code, like this: `eval('7*40')`. Read more about [eval](https://rubymonk.com/learning/books/5-metaprogramming-ruby-ascent/chapters/24-eval/lessons/63-eval).

Comment: Do not use **eval**, if some how someone hacks the service, and if you use `eval` for parsing then the code will get executed.

Answer (score 2):

You need to parse it with `JSON.parse`
Example:

```
parsed_hash = JSON.parse res.body
```

Result:

```
{
            "id" => "a3adasfaf3",
           "url" => "https://someurl/a3adasfaf3",
       "created" => "2016-05-30T07:00:58Z",
      "modified" => "2016-05-30T07:00:58Z",
    "files_hash" => "cljhlk2j3l2kj34hlke18",
      "language" => "ruby",
         "title" => "Some weird hello world message",
        "public" => false,
         "owner" => "kljhlk2jh34lk2jh4l2kj3h4l2kj4h23l4kjh2l4k",
         "files" => [
        [0] {
               "name" => "Some-weird-hello-world-message.rb",
            "content" => "puts \"Some weird hello world message.\"\r\n"
        }
    ]
}
```

To access the id:

```
parsed_hash['id']
```

To access the url:

```
parsed_hash['url']
```

Want to access it by symbols ?

```
parsed_hash = JSON.parse(res.body).symbolize_keys
```

You can now access id and url by `parsed_hash[:id]` and `parsed_hash[:url]`

Comment: What's the benefit to using `JSON.parse` over `eval(response)`?